# Is it ok to have blood in crease of vacuum seal? For steak and freezer

Tags: steak, vacuum

For vacuum sealing steaks for the freezer, is it ok to have blood/liquid in the crease?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXPD2.jpg

Comment: it's inside the sealed part, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the blood is inside the sealed part as indicated above, if the package conforms tightly to the contents and there are no air bubbles,loose wrinkles, or milkiness to the seal, then it is as air-tight as can be with retail machines, thus safe to eat, thus "ok". This link is pretty good for more info: [https://yourmeatguide.com/vacuum-sealed-meat-smells-bad/#:~:text=Check%20the%20seal%20prior%20to%20opening!&text=If%20the%20meat%20is%20loose,caused%20the%20meat%20to%20spoil](https://yourmeatguide.com/vacuum-sealed-meat-smells-bad/#:%7E:text=Check%20the%20seal%20prior%20to%20opening!&text=If%20the%20meat%20is%20loose,caused%20the%20meat%20to%20spoil).

In future, set the juicy meat in the vaccum bag and freeze it like that, then vacuum seal it, so you don't have a messy seal.